# how to code this design? img doesn't above div

Tags: html, css

I have a question.
I want to make this design.

[image]

Here is code.

```
   <section class="location">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="textbox">
        <p class="tit">address</p>
        <p class="sub_text">address</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

And here is css

```
section.location {
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: #608144;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

section.location .wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 270px;
  margin: auto;
}

section.location .wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/193x239.jpg");
  width: 193px;
  height: 239px;
  position: relative;
  top: -80%;
  right: 7%;
}
```

I try to use :after and position absolute, but it looks like this.

[image]

img doesn't above div. How to code this design?

Comment: have a look at z-index

Answer (score 2):

`z-index: 1;` or `99` if `1` doesn't work.

since all elements are layered, `z-index` determines which layers display with priority, so to speak. the higher the value of `z-index`, the fewer things that will obscure it.

an element with `z-index: 1` will obscure an element with `z-index: 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Make the z-index value higher than other used element.

```
section.location {
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: #608144;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;// added 
}

section.location .wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 270px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;// added 
}

section.location .wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/193x239.jpg");
  width: 193px;
  height: 239px;
  position: relative;
  top: -80%;
  right: 7%;
  z-index: 2;// added 
}
```